# GWT 2.7: Warn users they are using an unsupported browser

Tags: gwt, browser-detection, gwt-2.7

I recently upgraded my application to GWT 2.7 from GWT 2.5.  This has caused me to drop support for IE6 and IE7.

I would like to provide users with IE6 or IE7 with a warning that their browser is outdated and will not work.  At the moment if you go to the app with one of those browsers, you get a blank screen.

I know there are a couple ways that I could hack something together but I would rather use the *GWT way*, rather than some hack.  Is there a GWT hook for unsupported browsers?

**Option (hack) One**

Drop this into my main.html:

```
if(document.documentMode === 6 || document.documentMode === 7){
    myUnsupportedBrowserWarningFunction();
}
```

Potential problem with this is that if someone is using a browser that GWT doesn't recognise and I don't recognise (mobile opera?  Some other browser), they will still get a blank page.

**Option (hack) Two**

GWT looks for the compiled JS here:

```
gwt/myApp/ASDFKLSDJFLSFDJSLDFJLSJDFSDES.cache.js
```

When someone is using an unsupported browser the following is requested (and is not found):

```
gwt/myApp/undefined.cache.js
```

It would be possible to create `undefined.cache.js` and put your unsupported browser code there.  This is obviously a brittle solution and will break with future GWT updates.

**Option Three**

> A recent patch (available in GWT 2.7) allows you to provide a default
>   permutation (e.g. safari) if GWT can not detect the browser and with
>   deferred binding you can display a warning that the provided app might not
>   work correctly as the browser is generally unsupported by GWT.
>
> -- J.

[Source](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/google-web-toolkit/149hpfsryx/what-to-do-when-gwt-finds-no-permutation-for-browser)

I don't want to set a default permutation for unsupported browsers.  I want the site to not work and to display a warning.  So this solution doesn't really provide what I am looking for.

**Similar Questions & Posts**

- [The same question was asked for an eariler version of GWT in 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960393/gwt-unsupported-browser-warning).  I hope that GWT has added some kind of hook or best practice in the last 6 years.
- [More info on setting a default (fallback) permutation](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=8478)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `onLoadErrorFn` for that: https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=8135

```
<script>
  function gwtLoadError(errMsg) {
    // GWT app couldn't load, reason in errorMsg
  }
</script>
<meta name="gwt:onLoadErrorFn" content="gwtLoadError">
```

or possibly `onPropertyErrorFn`:

```
<script>
  function gwtPropError(propName, allowedValues, actualValue) {
    if (propName == 'user.agent') {
      // unsupported browser
    }
  }
</script>
<meta name="gwt:onPropertyErrorFn" content="gwtPropError">
```

(I don't think *user.agent.runtimeWarning* would help in this case, but maybe have a look)

Comment: that looks exactly like what I want to do.  Unfortunately, it doesn't work in my app.  I dropped that code into my main html page.  When I load the page in document mode 7, neither of those functions is called.

Answer (score -1):

There is an easy way:

[Conditional Comments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<p>You are using an unsupportet browser. Please perform an update</p>
<![endif]-->
```

I think Option 3 may be the best one, but there is a problem: This will start the actual application (which still may be incompatible).

If this is an issue and you want a clear warning, you can rewrite the permutation selection script (You would need to update the script with the upcoming GWT releases)

You will need to copy this source:

https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/2.7.0/user/src/com/google/gwt/useragent/rebind/UserAgentPropertyGenerator.java

You could add something like:

```
$wnd.Location.replace('nosupported.html');
```

between line 90 and 91

Comment: This solution is ok, but I would say that it is identical to my option #1.  It will be impossible to catch all browsers that aren't supported by GWT.

Comment: Thought it was about old IE browser.